# Taylor's Theorem for Multivariable Implict Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the $2$nd order Taylor polynomial for $z=g(x,y)$ near the point $(\frac {\pi}{2}, 1,1)$, given the function $\sin(xyz)=z^2$.  I've never found the Taylor polynomial of a function defined implicitly before, but I think I've got it. I'd just like it if someone could let me know if I did it right.

Here's my attempt:
So I've got the function $F(x,y,z)=\sin(xyz)-z^2=0$.  Where $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.  We know that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} =0$ by the chain rule.  Thus $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial_x F}{\partial_z F} = -\frac{\cos(xyz)}{\cos(xyz)-2z}$.

Likewise $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} =0$.  Then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial_y F}{\partial_z F} = -\frac{\cos(xyz)}{\cos(xyz)-2z}$.

Then the $2$nd derivatives are:
$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial x} = -\frac{\partial_x F\cdot(\partial_x\partial_z F) - \partial_z F\cdot(\partial_x\partial_x F)}{(\partial_z F)^2} = -\frac{\cos(xyz)(-\sin(xyz))-(\cos(xyz)-2z)(-\sin(xyz))}{(\cos(xyz)-2z)^2} = -\frac{2x}{(\cos(xyz)-2z)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y \partial y} = -\frac{\partial_y F\cdot(\partial_y\partial_z F) - \partial_z F\cdot(\partial_y\partial_y F)}{(\partial_z F)^2}=-\frac{2y}{(\cos(xyz)-2z)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y \partial x} = -\frac{\partial_y F\cdot(\partial_x\partial_z F) - \partial_z F\cdot(\partial_x\partial_y F)}{(\partial_z F)^2}=-\frac{\cos(xyz)(-\sin(xyz))-(\cos(xyz)-2z)(-\sin(xyz))}{(\cos(xyz)-2z)^2}$$

Then the Taylor polynomial will look like: $$g(\frac {\pi}2 + h_1, 1+ h_2) = 1 + \frac{\partial g(\frac{\pi}2, 1)}{\partial x}h_1 + \frac{\partial g(\frac{\pi}2, 1)}{\partial y}h_2 + \frac{\partial^2 g(\frac{\pi}2, 1)}{\partial x \partial x}\frac{h_1^2}{2!}+ \frac{\partial^2 g(\frac{\pi}2, 1)}{\partial y \partial y}\frac{h_2^2}{2!} + \frac{\partial^2 g(\frac{\pi}2, 1)}{\partial x \partial y}h_1 h_2$$

After plugging in values, I have a polynomial in $h_1$ and $h_2$, which I think is my solution.

---

Edit:  Also upon thinking about this, am I actually able to apply the chain rule like I did (in the second line under "Here's my attempt")?  That is I have a $\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}$ which is the derivative of $F$ holding $y$ and $z$ constant.  But because $z$ is a function of $x$, is this a legit move, or did I screw up right at the beginning?

Comment: Your Taylor polynomial looks correct to me.  However, take another look at your $2$nd derivatives -- they're not quite correct.  With regards to why you can apply the chain rule the way you did, consider the case $F(x,y)$, where $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$.  So both $x$ and $y$ "contain" a part of $t$, but you wouldn't have any problems if I wrote $\frac {\partial F}{\partial t} = \frac {\partial F}{\partial x} \frac {\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac {\partial F}{\partial y} \frac {\partial y}{\partial t}$, would you?