# Trying to understand polar coordinate vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to understand what the unit polar coordinate vectors (I'll denote them $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$) are and if they form a basis for $\Bbb R^2$.

So from what I understand, $\hat r$ points radially from the center and $\hat {\theta}$ points orthogonally to $\hat r$, as in the picture below:

[image]

Then a vector $\vec v$ could be represented by a linear combination of $\vec v$, i.e. $\vec v=a \hat r + b \hat \phi$.  My question is, if $\{\hat r,\hat \phi\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^2$, then knowing $(a,b)$ should completely specify any point, right?  But I don't understand how either $\hat r$ or $\hat \phi$ specify the angle that the vector makes with the positive $x$-axis (or whatever that reference line is called in polar coordinates).  I can see how, if you know the Cartesian representation of $\hat r$ or $\hat \phi$, you can then determine the other and thus specify any point, but can you specify any point in the plane without a conversion to Cartesian first?  If not, why are $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$ even useful?

---

**Edit**:
Muphrid does a good job of explaining why trying to think of $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$ as basis vectors of $\Bbb R^2$ isn't the best way to use them.  But in case anyone who reads this *is* interested in where they come from, how to use them, and how to derive the relations for the grad, div, and curl, [I found this pretty good set of lecture notes](http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/footer/courses/m225/handouts/divgradcurl3.pdf).

Comment: What you are calling $\hat\phi$ is not what corresponds to the typical angular component in polar coordinates.

Comment: Well, in class, polar coordinates just meant that $\vec v = r\cos(\theta)\hat i + r\sin(\theta)\hat j$, but I've seen discussions of $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$ before.  And I'm trying to get my head around what they are.

Comment: Is this in regards to Newton's 2nd law?

Comment: @dustin  I'm not thinking about it specifically in terms of Newton's law.  I'm just wondering about the math.

Comment: I ask because I have some notes that discuss in detail the change of coordinates.

Comment: @dustin  Feel free to post them.  Berci hasn't answered my question adequately, yet (whether because I'm just not understanding his answer or he's not understanding my question, IDK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basis vectors $\hat r, \hat \phi$ are vector **fields**.  It happens to be true that, for any point described by $(r_0, \phi_0)$, then a vector describing that position is equal to $r_0\hat r(r_0, \phi_0)$.  That...may only be marginally useful.

Nevertheless, given a point $(r_0, \phi_0)$, the **values** of those vector fields at that point--i.e. $\hat r(r_0, \phi_0)$ and $\hat \phi(r_0, \phi_0)$--span a 2d vector space.  This is called the *tangent space* at the point $(r_0, \phi_0)$.  This is not suitable for describing positions (see note), but it is suitable for describing, among other things, the vectors tangent to curves that go through the point $(r_0, \phi_0)$.

Note:  you could, of course, choose some arbitrary $(r_0, \phi_0)$ to evaluate $\hat r, \hat \phi$, and then those **values** span $\mathbb R^2$, but the choice of a point there is arbitrary and not related to any particular position you want to describe.

Comment: Could you give an example of how we'd use $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$?

Comment: They're going to arise naturally any time you have some curve that respects radial or angular symmetry.  Integrating over a circle, for instance, allows you to write the tangent to the circle merely as proportional to $\hat \phi$.

Comment: OK, so say I'm doing a line integral over the circle given by $x^2+y^2-2y=0$, through the vector field $xy^2\hat i + (y^2+x^2)\hat j + \hat k$ (I just made that up, so sorry if it doesn't work out very well), how would the vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$ (and $\hat \theta$) be used to solve it?

Comment: You could write the vector field as a linear combination of the vector fields $\hat r, \hat \phi$ and then just throw away the $\hat r$ if it's a dot product line integral, or throw away the $\hat \phi$ component if it's a cross product line integral.

Comment: Why could I just throw out $\hat r$ -- notice that I shifted the circle up, so $r$ won't be constant (unless we also shift the coordinates up).  Also, I've never used a cross product line integral.  I was talking about a line integral of the form $\int_C F \cdot dr$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, yes, in these coordinates you wouldn't be able to throw out a component.  So, life would be tough: either you do another coordinate transformation to shift the circle to the origin, or you live with the coordinate system you have.

Comment: I was thinking about it, couldn't we just say that the polar coordinate transformation takes the vectors $x\hat x + y\hat y$ to vectors $r\hat r + \phi \hat \phi$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi=\arctan|\frac yx|$.  Then we could represent these coordinates on a coordinate graph that looks exactly like the one for the $xy$-plane, except that one axis is called the $r$-axis and the other is called the $\phi$-axis.  Then vectors in the $r\phi$-plane would add the right way.  The mapping wouldn't be bijective, though.  But at least you could represent positions with $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$.

Comment: That's not true, though.  The polar coordinate representation of a position $x \hat x + y \hat y$ is $r \hat r$.

Comment: Alright.  I'll have to spend some time thinking about this.  Thanks, though.  I'll go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: BTW, could you take a look at [the question I asked yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022105/taylors-theorem-for-multivariable-implict-functions).  I was just hoping for someone to tell me if I did it right, or if not, why.

Answer (score 5):

Well, your vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat\phi$, as the picture greatly shows, form a basis.

The polar coordinates of a point are just $r$ and $\phi$: the distance from origin, and the angle enclosed with the positive wing of the $x$-axis.

If you consider the length of your vectors as $|\hat r|=|\hat\phi|=r\ $ then these vectors are just the $x$ and $y$ directional derivatives of the function $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$
$$(r,\phi)\ \mapsto\ (r\cos\phi,\,r\sin\phi)$$
i.e. which takes $(r,\phi)$ to the point it represents as polar coordinates (the point in your picture).

Comment: Why are you setting $|\hat r|=|\hat \phi|$?  And what do directional derivatives have to do with representing arbitary points by the unit vector $\hat r$and $\hat \phi$? I'm not so much looking for a way to represent vector-valued functions (just yet) as just how to represent points in the plane. So for instance, if I had the vector $\vec v = 2\hat r+3\hat \phi$, would I know where exactly it was in $\Bbb R^2$ without any other information?  If so, how?  If not, why are $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$ even useful?

Answer (score 3):

> On the topic of Newton's 2$^{\text{nd}}$ from Cartesian to polar.
>   Converting from my $\LaTeX$ notes to mathjax is a pain.

---

In Cartesian coordinates, we can write the vector $\mathbf{r}$ as $x\hat{\mathbf{x}} + y\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ where $x = r\cos(\phi)$, $y = r\sin(\phi)$, $\lVert \mathbf{r}\rVert = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and $\phi = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ see figure.
[image]

Since we have two independent unit vectors, we can write our force as a linear combination of the basis vectors $\{\hat{\mathbf{r}}, \pmb{\phi}\}$.
$$
  \mathbf{F} = F_r\hat{\mathbf{r}} + F_{\phi}\pmb{\phi}
  \tag{1}
$$

---

> What is $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$?

---

\begin{align}
  \dot{\mathbf{r}} &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(
    \lVert\mathbf{r}\rVert\hat{\mathbf{r}}\right)\\
  &= \dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + r\frac{d\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{dt}\tag{2}
\end{align}
[image]

Let $\Delta t = t_2 - t_1 \ll 1$.
From the figure directly above, we have that $\Delta\mathbf{r} = \Delta\phi\pmb{\phi}$.
  \begin{align*}
    \Delta\mathbf{r} &= \Delta\phi\pmb{\phi}\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t}\\
    &= \dot{\phi}\Delta t\pmb{\phi}
    \tag{since \(\frac{\Delta\phi}{\Delta t} = \dot{\phi}\)}\\
    \frac{\Delta\mathbf{r}}{\Delta t} &= \dot{\phi}\pmb{\phi}\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
Now we can take the limit of equation (3) as $\Delta t\to 0$.
Thus, we have that
\begin{align}
  \lim\limits_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{\Delta\mathbf{r}}{\Delta t} &=
  \dot{\phi}\pmb{\phi}\\
  \frac{d\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{dt} &= \dot{\phi}\pmb{\phi}\tag{4}
\end{align}
Now we can plug equation (4) into equation (2) to obtain
\begin{align}
  \dot{\mathbf{r}} &= \dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + r\dot{\phi}\pmb{\phi}.
  \tag{5}
\end{align}
Since $\dot{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{v}$, we can write equation (5) in component form of velocity, $\mathbf{v} = v_r\hat{\mathbf{r}} + v_{\phi}\pmb{\phi}$.
Then $v_r = \dot{r}$ and $v_{\phi} = r\dot{\phi}$.
Note that $\omega$ is used instead of $\dot{\phi}$ in many textbooks as well.
We will also be using $\omega$ and $\dot{\phi}$ interchangeable throughout the notes. In order to define Newton's $2^{\text{2nd}}$ Law in polar coordinates, we still need to determine $\mathbf{a} = \ddot{\mathbf{r}}$.
\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{a} &= \ddot{\mathbf{r}}\\
  &= \frac{d}{dt}\dot{\mathbf{r}}\\
  &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + r\dot{\phi}\pmb{\phi}\right)\\
  &= \ddot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + \dot{r}\frac{d\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{dt} +
  \dot{r}\dot{\phi}\pmb{\phi} + r\ddot{\phi}\pmb{\phi} +
  r\dot{\phi}\frac{d\pmb{\phi}}{dt}\\
  &= \ddot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + 2\dot{r}\dot{\phi}\pmb{\phi} + r\ddot{\phi}\pmb{\phi}
  + r\dot{\phi}\frac{d\pmb{\phi}}{dt}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
[image]

From figure above, we see that
$\Delta\pmb{\phi} \approx \Delta\phi\hat{\mathbf{r}}$.
  \begin{align*}
    \Delta\pmb{\phi} &\approx \Delta\phi\hat{\mathbf{r}}\\
    &= \Delta\phi\hat{\mathbf{r}}\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t}\\
    &= -\dot{\phi}\hat{\mathbf{r}}\Delta t
    \tag{since $\frac{\Delta\phi}{\Delta t} = \dot{\phi}$}\\
    \frac{\Delta\pmb{\phi}}{\Delta t} &= -\dot{\phi}\hat{\mathbf{r}}\tag{7}
  \end{align*}
Taking the limit of equation (7) as $\Delta t\to 0$, we have
\begin{align}
  \lim\limits_{\Delta t\to 0} \frac{\Delta\pmb{\phi}}{\Delta t} &=
  -\dot{\phi}\hat{\mathbf{r}}\\
  \frac{d\pmb{\phi}}{dt} &= -\dot{\phi}\hat{\mathbf{r}}\tag{8}
\end{align}
Plugging in equation (8) into equation (6) and grouping, we obtain
$$
  \ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \left(\ddot{r} - r\dot{\phi}^2\right)\hat{\mathbf{r}} +
  \left(2\dot{r}\dot{\phi} + r\ddot{\phi}\right)\pmb{\phi}.
  \tag{9}
$$
Now we can write $\mathbf{F} = m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ in component form
\begin{align}
  F_r &= m\left(\ddot{r} - r\dot{\phi}^2\right)\tag{10}\\
  F_{\phi} &= \left(2\dot{r}\dot{\phi} + r\ddot{\phi}\right)\tag{11}
\end{align}
If the radius is constant (a circle), then $\dot{r} = \ddot{r} = 0$.
For a circle,
  \begin{align}
    \frac{F_r}{m} &= -r\dot{\phi}^2\tag{angular velocity}\\
    \frac{F_{\phi}}{m} &= r\ddot{\phi}\tag{angular acceleration}
  \end{align}

Comment: OK, so if I understand this correctly: if you represent a vector $\vec g$ in the basis $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$, then the coefficient on $\hat r$ is just the length of the vector and the coefficient on $\hat \phi$ is the angle of the vector.  That does specify the vector exactly in $\Bbb R^2$, but it's pretty weird.  Because multiplying the coefficient on $\hat \phi$ will not only change the length of vector $\phi \hat \phi$, but it will rotate it.  Thus the directions of $\hat \phi$ & $\hat r$ are determined *by the coefficient on $\hat \phi$*.  If that's not correct, let me know.

Comment: @user192605 yes the coefficient for $\hat{r}$ is the distance from the origin and for $\hat{\phi}$, it is the angle measured up from the x axis.