# Angle between tangent vector and point of a cardiod.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, plane-curves

Consider the cardioid $\rho=2a\left( 1 - \cos \phi \right) $. Show that the angle between the tangent vector and an arbitrary point (different from the origin) of the curve is half the polar angle.

---

Expressed in polar coordinates, I have the curve

$$\mathbf x \left( \phi \right) = \left( \rho, \phi \right) = \left( 2a\left( 1 - \cos \phi \right), \phi \right) $$

I tried to do the problem using cartesian coordinates, as I am used to do, but things were not nice. So I have looked up the formula for the tangent vector in polar coordinates (and I understood where it comes from).

$$\mathbf t _ \mathbf x \left( \phi \right) = \left( \frac{ \mathrm d \rho}{\mathrm d \phi}, \rho \right) = \left( 2 a \sin \phi, \rho \right)=\left( 2 a \sin \phi, 2a \left( 1 - \cos \phi \right) \right)$$

Then I know that the angle $\theta$ between these two vectors is given by

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\left\langle \mathbf x , \mathbf t _\mathbf x \right\rangle }{\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert \left\Vert \mathbf{t}_\mathbf x\right\Vert }$$

And the inner product in polar coordinates is the product of the first coordinates times the cosine of the difference of the second coordinates, so

$$\left\langle \mathbf x , \mathbf t _\mathbf x \right\rangle = 4 a^2 \sin \phi \left( 1 - \cos \phi \right) \cos \left( \phi - \rho \right)$$

The norms of each vector are the first coordinate as they are in polar form, so

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\left\langle \mathbf x , \mathbf t _\mathbf x \right\rangle }{\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert \left\Vert \mathbf{t}_\mathbf x\right\Vert }=\frac{4a^2\sin \phi \left( 1-\cos \phi \right) \cos \left( \phi - \rho \right)}{4a^2 \sin\phi \left( 1 - \cos \phi \right) }=\cos \left(\phi - \rho \right)$$

So $\theta = \phi - \rho + 2 \pi n$, where $\rho=2a\left( 1 - \cos \phi \right) $, but I think I have to prove that $\theta = \frac{\phi}{2}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you may be mixing up two things. Your inner product formula applies to two vectors from the origin to two given sets of polar coordinates, but the formula you seem to have in mind for ${\mathbf t}_{\mathbf x}(\phi)$ is actually $\frac{d\rho}{d\phi} {\mathbf e}_\rho + \rho  {\mathbf e}_\phi$, which is not at all the same thing as the polar coordinates $\left(\frac{d\rho}{d\phi}, \rho\right)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the differente between the two expressions. The first is given as a linear combination of the vectors of the basis and the second is the ordered pair of the coefficients. Is $\mathbf {x} \left( \phi \right) = \left( \rho, \phi \right)$ wrong too?

Comment: Unlike in Cartesian coordinates, the vectors of the basis of polar coordinates _are different at different points on the plane._ It's fine to write $\mathbf x(\phi) = (\rho,\phi)$, but in this notation $\rho$ and $\phi$ are not coefficients of basis vectors.

Comment: Here's another question showing the vectors $\mathbf e_\rho$ and $\mathbf e_\phi$ (except that in the diagram in that question, these vectors are labeled $\hat{\mathbf r}$ and $\hat{\bf\phi}$): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023469/trying-to-understand-polar-coordinate-vectors

Comment: So, if I find a way to write the tangent vector in polar coordinates, then the rest of the reasoning might be valid?

Comment: That sounds like it would work. An alternative method is to convert the tangent vectors to Cartesian coordinates.